# Styling cell in Kendo grid via ClientTemplate

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-grid, kendo-asp.net-mvc

I'm attempting to style the 'containing' cell in a kendo (mvc) grid.  The column is bound as follows:

```
@(Html.Kendo().Grid(Of RTFVM)().Name("RealTimeFinancials") _
 .Columns(Sub(c)
                  c.Bound(Function(x) x.Line.Months(0).Total).Title("Jan").ClientTemplate("#= processCell(Line.Months[0])#")
etc
```

And my JS conditional styling function is as follows:

```
 function processCell(CellData) {
    var monthNumber = CellData.MonthNumber;
    var output;

    switch(CellData.Message) {
        case null: output = fn(CellData.Total); break;
        case 'Total': output = '<div style="background-color: Red;"><strong>' + fn(CellData.Total) + '</strong></div>';
            break;
        default: output = '<small>' + CellData.Message + '</small>';
    }

    return output;
}
```

Using the above I can style the *text* that appears in the cell but apparently not the cell itself (I guess you could call it the text object's 'parent'/container).

Is there any way to access/style the cell from within the ClientTemplate or do I have to separately find the cell by using the databound event using the data-uid row/column-find method?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After much research and a helping nudge from Satya I found a broad generic solution based on Daniel's answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11270288/how-do-i-change-the-background-color-of-a-kendo-ui-for-mvc-grid-cell) - though it only seems to work partially:

I have created a function which attempts to style the row based on the value of a field on the datasource triggered on the grid.databound event:

```
function LineItems_Databound() {
    var grid = $("#RealTimeFinancials").data("kendoGrid");
    var data = grid.dataSource.data();
    $.each(data, function (i, row) {
        var LineItem = row.Message;

        switch(LineItem) {
            case 'Total': $('tr[data-uid="' + row.uid + '"]').addClass('customClass'); break;        
        }
    });
}
```

customClass is:

```
.customClass {
        border-top-style:double;
        border-style:double;
        border-top-width:thick;
        background-color:lightyellow;
    }`
```

The issue I have (and it occurs also when simply setting the .css on the grid ) is that whilst the background color of the row is changed, the grid borders are not.  I cannot seem to style the cell/row borders at all.

I think it does answer the broad question I had, though in this scenario there are still issues.

I've opened a separate question to address the apparent css class issue [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26992745/unable-to-style-borders-of-a-row-of-kendo-grid)

Comment: For completeness (and feeding back that learnt in my other question) the reason the above doesn't work for the borders is that the tr elements don't take border formatting whereas td elements (cells) do. For the above to work it is necessary to iterate over the td's within the tr and apply the class as described: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26992745/unable-to-style-borders-of-a-row-of-kendo-grid

Answer (score 2):

Try like:

Add a class/id to the output "div" that is returned from the "processCell" function and using that class get the parent element of the cell and add styling to that cell.
Hope it works!

Comment: Thanks for this and apologies for being slow:  I'm not sure what object I could use to get the parent element of the cell.  All that I have in scope in processCell is the data item itself and I can't see how to inject the appropriate object from the grid-level context via ClientTemplate... Or are you saying to use purely CSS to navigate back up the DOM?

Comment: Try like:

col.Bound(e => e.Name).ClientTemplate("<div id='xyz' style='background: #F7F7F7;'>#= Name #<div>")

and on dataBound event call a javascript function which will get the cell element using the id i.e "xyz" and with that use the .parent() function to get the row element of the grid and style it.

Comment: Ok thanks - you led me to Daniel's solution (see above) which I think does answer the question even though it doesn't seem effective for all styles.

Comment: I am glad that you got some answer. I will also try the solution you have provided and if possible will come up with some better solution.:)

Comment: I've opened a separate question for this issue: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26992745/unable-to-style-borders-of-a-row-of-kendo-grid