# Unable to style borders of a row of Kendo grid

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-grid, kendo-asp.net-mvc

I'm attempting to style an MVC kendo grid based on values in the underlying datasource.  I have a mechanism that seems to work, but certain style elements (notably borders) do not seem to accept the new style class, whereas other elements (row background color) work fine.

Grid:

```
@(Html.Kendo().Grid(Of RTFVM)().Name("RealTimeFinancials") _
 .Events(Function(x) x.DataBound("LineItems_Databound")) _
 .Columns(Sub(c)
                  c.Bound(Function(x) x.Line.LineItem).HtmlAttributes(New With {.style = "text-align:left"})
etc
```

Event handler:

```
 function LineItems_Databound() {
    var grid = $("#RealTimeFinancials").data("kendoGrid");
    var data = grid.dataSource.data();
    $.each(data, function (i, row) {
        var LineItem = row.Message;

        switch(LineItem) {
            case 'SubTotal': $('tr[data-uid="' + row.uid + '"]').css({ "border-style":"solid", "border-top":"single","background-color":"yellow"}); break;
            case 'Total': $('tr[data-uid="' + row.uid + '"]').addClass('customClass'); break;
            case 'GrandTotal': $('tr[data-uid="' + row.uid + '"]').css({ "border-style":"solid", "border-bottom":"double"}); break;
        }
    });
}
```

CSS Class:

```
  .customClass {
    border-top-style:double;
    border-style:double;
    border-top-width:thick;
    background-color:lightyellow;
}
```

Neither the .css or the .addClass have any effect on the row border style, whilst both happily change the background color of the row.

Is it that I need to do this at a cell-level?  But that seems odd given the background color works row-wise.

Answer (score 4):

Border property does not work with tr it only works with td so you can do what you need like that:

```
.k-grid .customClass {
    background-color:lightyellow;
}

.k-grid .customClass td {
    border-top-style:double;
    border-style:double;
    border-top-width:thick;
}
```

Alternatively you can use `outline` property for tr but it styles whole border - you can't specify separately left, right, top and bottom border:

```
.k-grid .customClass {
    outline: thick double;
}
```

Comment: Thank you - I hadn't realised that.  Adding the 'td' to the customClass still doesn't seem to work though - I assume I therefore need to iterate over the td's in the tr and apply classes to the td's.

Comment: OK - well I tried iterating over the td's and I get the same result - the color changes but not the borders:  case 'Total': $('tr[data-uid="' + row.uid + '"]').find('td').each(function () { $(this).addClass('customClass') }); break;

Comment: Hmm... Try something like this for me please: `.k-grid .customClass td` instead of `.customClass td` it's stronger selector than `.k-grid td` itself.

Comment: If I do that I lose the background color as well.  HOWEVER - using simply the .customClass selector and adding '!important' works - so I think it seems my code is painting the cells before Kendo?  Which seems odd.  This doesn't feel like the best solution somehow.

Comment: !important is finality and we should avoid it. But I do not understand why you are losing background color in my solution. Don't you want to have your background color in all rows with customClass?

Comment: Ok - it's the td which was causing the problem (apologies I'd left all the style statements in that group which is why colour wasn't working either).  So this now works as .k-grid .customClass {....} without any !Important's.  So (excluding the td) this is an answer - thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Kendo grid's row borders can be changed as shown below,

```
<style>
.k-grid tr {
    border-bottom: 1px solid black;
}
</style>
```

This can be extended and manipulated according to the need. i.e., `.k-grid tr td` or `.k-grid th` or `.k-grid table` and etc.

Answer (score 0):

I found this answer thanks to a combination of @j4ro's response in respect of styling the td rather than the row and researching how to iterate across td's in the tr applying the class.  So - the javascript to iterate over the row is:

```
 case 'Total': $('tr[data-uid="' + row.uid + '"]').find('td') _
     .each(function () { $(this).addClass('customClass') }); break;
```

and the class is defined as (and I guess the key thing is the introduction of the k.grid reference):

```
.k-grid .customClass {
   border-top-style:double
   border-style:double;
   border-top-width:thick;
  }
```